# Pandas .loc on multindex only 2nd level

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a multiindex pandas dataframe, and I want to select all values from the 1st level indices (here denoted as *x* and a specific index from the 2nd level, here it is the mean of the .describe() function after grouping.

```
df.groupby(df1.series).describe().loc[*x*,'mean']
```

How do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you think `df.groupby(df1.series).describe().loc[(*x*,'mean')]` ?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tuple for select:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[4,5,7,6,10], 'series':list('xxxyy')})
b = df.x.groupby(df.series).describe().stack()
print (b)
series       
x       count     3.000000
        mean      5.333333
        std       1.527525
        min       4.000000
        25%       4.500000
        50%       5.000000
        75%       6.000000
        max       7.000000
y       count     2.000000
        mean      8.000000
        std       2.828427
        min       6.000000
        25%       7.000000
        50%       8.000000
        75%       9.000000
        max      10.000000
dtype: float64

c = b.loc[('x','mean')]
print (c)
5.33333333333
```

If want all means use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
c = b.xs('mean', level=1)
print (c)
series
x    5.333333
y    8.000000
dtype: float64
```